# How to find unique entries in mappings?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, arrays, mapping

Is it possible to write a function that compares a list of strings or numbers, or both, and determines which items in the list are uniques?

could someone provide sample code of how that would be done using any of the main languages.

Comment: in solidity I guess ?

Comment: ah yes. i'm also looking for an code example of how to do this of going through an array and checking all the items and returning those which are uniques or filtering out those which have duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a mapping wrapper, that will have "contains" method.

Something like here : https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/library/iterable_mapping.sol

Comment: Please consider adding more information to your post as links may break in the future.